# "Global surjective theorem"

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

So in Multivariate analysis we are doing mapping Theorems and we had one homework problem that I have not been able to solve for over a day now.

$ g: \mathbb{R^p \to R^p}\,\text{belongs to class $C^1(\mathbb R^p)$ and satisfies $\|\mathbf Dg(x)\|_{pp} \le a < 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^p$. }$

where $\|\mathbf Dg(x)\|_{pp}$ is the operator norm of the derivative.

Now we have $f(x) = x + g(x)\, \forall x \in \mathbb R^p$ we have to show that $f$ satisfies the following:
$$ \|f(x_1) - f(x_2) - (x_1 - x_2)\| \le a\|x_1 - x_2 \|$$ and that $f$ is a bijection of $ {\mathbb{R}^p \, onto \, \, \mathbb{R}^p}$

My attempt at a solution has been quite futile, I attempted using the approximation lemma and run an iterative scheme to get the inequality but could not in the end,

Any guidance would be very helpful

EDIT: so after i wrote the problem down I believe that the Mean Value Theorem solves the first part (the inequality) as it is equivalent to saying $$ \|g(x_1) - g(x_2)\| \le \|Dg(x)\| . \|x_1 - x_2\|$$ which is granted by the Mean value theorem of higher dimensions, but the bijection part still eludes me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some hints:

- $\mathbf{D}f = I + \mathbf{D}g$ is invertible at each point. By the inverse function theorem, $f$ is an open mapping.
- By the reverse triangle inequality,
  $$
  \|f(x_{1}) - f(x_{2})\| \geq \|x_{1} - x_{2}\| - \|g(x_{1}) - g(x_{2})\|.
  $$
  Combined with your estimate for $\|g(x_{1}) - g(x_{2})\|$, you can establish $f$ is injective. In particular, $f$ is a homeomorphism when restricted to an arbitrary closed ball.
- The final estimate from the preceding point (with $x_{2} = 0$) shows that the sphere of radius $R$ centered at the origin maps outside the open ball $B$ of radius $R(1 - a)$ centered at $f(0)$, so [*] $B$ is contained in the image of $f$. That essentially gives you surjectivity.

[*] The starred deduction entails a topological argument. If you don't have theorems to handle this, e.g., the [Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem#Proof_and_generalizations), you might instead try to prove the image of $f$ is closed, since you already know the image is open. Offhand, however, I don't see a way to avoid topological machinery equivalent to the separation theorem.